# how to use extended partion on ext3

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have got a new ubuntu server, which I can access as root:
and I can see the following partitions.

```
/dev/sda1  *          2048     782335     780288  381M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2           784382 3907028991 3906244610  1.8T  5 Extended
/dev/sda5           784384 3856726015 3855941632  1.8T 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       3856728064 3907028991   50300928   24G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

but when I use df -h
I can see it like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  169M  1.5G  11% /run
/dev/sda5       1.8T  6.8G  1.7T   1% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       361M   54M  289M  16% /boot
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

My question is how can I use `/dev/sda2`?

I tried like this:

```
root@server2:/# sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/backup
```

but get this error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Comment: `sda2` is what contains `sda5` and `sda6`.  See http://www.linfo.org/extended_partition.html

Comment: you mean there is only one hdd? but then how the same hdd have ext3 and ext4 type partitin?

Comment: You can have more partitions than just one.  You can have NTFS, ext2, ext3, ext4 and swap all on the same drive.  Extended is used to create more partitions on a type of partitioning scheme, like msdos that only supports 4 primary partitions.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning

Comment: And the `/dev/sda` is the first drive.  The numbers after the `sda` are the partition numbers.

Comment: Thanks. is there any way to find, if there is any other drive attached to the system.

Comment: Running commands like `parted -l` or `fdisk -l` will list all.  You can also run programs like `lsblk` but make sure you look for ones that begin with `sd` as those are the hard drives.  You might see things like loop which are just mounted files.

Comment: The `/sys/class/block` directory shows links to directories holding block (disk-style) devices. This directory identifies whole disk devices, partitions, optical drives, and some more exotic things. *Most* disk devices in Ubuntu have names of the form `sd?`, where `?` is a single letter from `a` upward, and partitions are identified by following letters (`sda1`, for instance). Some newer NVMe devices have names of the form `nvme#n#` (say, `nvme0n1`, with partitions adding `p#` (as in `nvme0n1p1`).